# Creating keyword records in a database

Tags: c#, database

This code is part of a data model used to create keyword records in a database.

```
if (_queue
    .OrderByDescending(record=>record.Primary)
    .GroupBy(record=>record.Term)
    .Select(record=>record.First())
    .Select(Create)
    .Any(result=>result <= 0))
{
    throw new ModelException("Failed to create keyword record.");
}
```

While I can understand this, I was also thinking it was a little obfuscated.

Is the intent of this code clearly readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely readable although I would just combine your two `select` statements and add some whitespace:

```
if (_queue.OrderByDescending(record => record.Primary)
          .GroupBy(record => record.Term)
          .Select(record => Create(record.First()))
          .Any(result => result <= 0))
{
    throw new ModelException("Failed to create keyword record.");
}
```

As you see I also prefer to keep the first statement on the same line and indent the next statements to align with the linq statement.

One remark though: first you're ordering your records and then grouping them. Is this done deliberately? I would assume that you'd want to group first and then order, not in the least because you would have to order less elements. But then again: grouping might be more performant if you order it first so I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Yeah, ordering first is done deliberately. I'm basically removing duplicate keywords, but I need to make sure that ones marked Primary (true/false) are kept marked as primary. So I just order them to be first.

Comment: Dropping the second Select has made this much easier to read now. Thanks.